# jQuery HTML form, selected file is not available in PHP $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have a form that with a link click adds a new  for a file with jquery's .html()

```
    // show div to change image on product_edit.php
    $("#change_img").click(
        function () {
            $("#change_img_div").html('<label>Image product</label><input type="file" value="" name="item_img" id="item_img"/>').fadeIn('fast');
            $(this).fadeOut('fast');

        }
    )
```

When I choose a file and I submit this name "item_img" is not present in the php $_POST array,
if I put type="text" instead the new input is passed to POST.

Basically seems like a "file" type is not recognized if this is not present in the html if the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files are sent as binary data and as per the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html), it requires the `<form>` to be set with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so that it can be mixed with text content (the normal request parameters). In the PHP side, they are available by the [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) array.

#### See also:

- [W3schools - PHP File Upload example](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp)
- [Tizag.com - PHP File Upload tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)
- [A lot more PHP File Upload tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+upload+file+tutorial)